# Navigation Bar Shrinking after relaunching app

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, navigationbar, shrink

I got a problem, I need to build something similar to this, where the red bar is a UIImageView and the blue bar is the navigation bar:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/30/iqtt.png

I was able to make it with the following code, my problem is that when I press home button to close the app and reopen it, my navigation bar shrinks, on the link image it has 88px and after relaunch 44px, so it mess with my layout.

Here is the code I've used on viewDidAppear:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
         [super viewDidAppear:animated];
         self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88);

         v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
         UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 5, 255, 29)];
         [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-logo"]];
         [v addSubview:img];
         [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:v];
    }
```

How could I fix that behavior?

Comment: try -(void)viewDidAppear{ self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88);} And in viewWillAppear too.

Comment: I already tried, but after relaunch, it doesn't work! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should never change navigation bar frame.Instead hide the navigation bar ,and create your custom view and add it to top of self.view.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);;

 // v is our total 88px height navigation bar
 v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88)];
 UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 5, 255, 29)];
 [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-logo"]];
 [v addSubview:img];

 UIView *navigationBar = //create nav bar with buttons of height 44px
 [v addSubview:navigationBar];

[self.view addSubview:v];
```

Comment: Yes, I tought it should be the only way. I gonna do like that, Thanks!