# Navigation Bar - Padding after relaunching app

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am setting a custom height for the navigation bar, also the status bar is hidden:

[image: hidden status bar]

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 60)
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

I also tried:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40)

}
```

but after relaunching app there is a kind of padding on the top:

[image]

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346224/navigation-bar-shrinking-after-relaunching-app):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 60))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar);
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Add");
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(addNewRecipe(_:)));
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem;
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false);
    view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

Is there another way than hiding the navigation bar and writing each navigation items programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Details

xCode 8.3, Swift 3.1

### Full sample

> Classes

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12118" systemVersion="16E195" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="NJV-2W-zhz">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12086"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Main-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_43295886" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Main" id="CEB-N4-YPg"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="897" y="791"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="rqG-Xx-QcO">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="NJV-2W-zhz" customClass="NavigationController" customModule="stackoverflow_43295886" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="klc-WP-4es">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="vdV-Sr-o02"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Dng-hb-kZ9" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="133.59999999999999" y="791.15442278860576"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

[image]

### Result

[image]